# PGFPlots: Axis dashed

Tags: pgfplots

How to configure axis dashed on PGFPlots?

```
\begin{axis}[grid=major]
%need grid=dashed
\end{axis}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `grid style` option (for each grid line), or `major grid style` (for each major grid line):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major]
%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you only want to activate the dashing of the grid on a per-plot basis, then you can put the command in the axis command, i.e. `\begin{axis}[grid=major,grid style={dashed}]`.